# Algorithm to sum all the numbers in the string

Tags: algorithm, tree

I am trying to figure out an algorithm to sum all the numbers in a string.

Input : "1 + (2 * 3) + [4 / 4])"
Output: 8

What is an efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: Why is the answer 8?

Comment: @0x499602D2 what else would it be?  
1 + (2*3) + (4/4) = 1 + 6 + 1 = 8

Comment: Well, yes, but that is not "to sum all the numbers".

Comment: I think OP is trying to evaluate all mathematical expressions in the string.  In which case, OP would need to parse the string into a tree of expressions and then evaluate it.